# new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl); --- Object does not support this action

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model

```
var siteUrl='sites/mysite';

function wait(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    ....more code....
}
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', wait());
```

> ERROR:  Object does not support this action

I am writing this JavaScript on a custom list EditForm in SP 2013.

What's wrong?

Comment: check this http://mahmoudfarhat.net/post/2013/03/23/SharePoint-2013-ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded-not-executing-after-page-publish.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', wait());` will invoke method `wait()` to evaluate the parameter value.

To `SP.SOD.executeFunc` you should pass the function name as below

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', wait);
```

Comment: That modification gets me...  Error: 'ClientContext' is undefined

Comment: @Das it seems issue with the way you are referencing the JS files. Can you post how you have added the sp js file in master page?

Comment: I have not added sp.js to the master page.  Perhaps that is the issue?  When I arrived here, they did have the site rebranded.  How/where would I add sp.js to the master page?  Your guidance and feedback is appreciated!!

Comment: @Das follow this article http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2013/10/30/how-to-properly-reference-sp-js-in-a-master-page/

Comment: Will try the above on Monday and report back.  Thx!